How do I consolidate a dataframe with duplicate names in one column with different results in another column in R?
I have a large R data.frame where I have duplicate chemical names with different "Result" and "Use" values in a second column. I want to consolidate these so I have a single row per chemical, and all "Result" and "Use" values are comma separated in a single cell in each of their respective columns.
example df:
df1 <- data.frame(Name=c("reservatol","reservatol","reservatol","DPG"),
                  Result = c("naturally occurring", "antagonist", "synthetic", "rubber"),
                  Use = c("Pharma", "Pharma", "Drugs and Medication", "Tires"))

  Name              Result                     Use
1 reservatol        naturally occurring        Pharma
2 reservatol        antagonist                 Pharma
3 reservatol        synthetic                  Drugs and Medication
4 DPG               rubber                     Tires

Is there a way to make that look like this?
  Name           Result                                         Use
1 reservatol     naturally occurring, antagonist, synthetic     Pharma, Drugs and Medication
2 DPG            rubber                                         Tires

I tried using group_by("Name") %>% mutate(Use = paste0(Result, collapse=",") in hopes of concatenating Uses, but it didn't seem to do anything.

You were almost there - use summarise instead of mutate:
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  summarise(Result = paste(Result, collapse = ", "), Use = paste(Use, collapse = ", "))


Using base R aggregate
> aggregate(.~Name, FUN = function(x) paste0(x, collapse = ","), data = df1)
        Name                                   Result                                Use
1        DPG                                   rubber                              Tires
2 reservatol naturally occurring,antagonist,synthetic Pharma,Pharma,Drugs and Medication

Or even shorter:
> aggregate(.~Name, FUN = \(x) c(x), data = df1)
        Name                                     Result                                  Use
1        DPG                                     rubber                                Tires
2 reservatol naturally occurring, antagonist, synthetic Pharma, Pharma, Drugs and Medication

Using dplyr:
> df1 %>% 
    summarise(across(everything(), ~paste0(.x, collapse = ",")), .by = Name)
        Name                                   Result                                Use
1 reservatol naturally occurring,antagonist,synthetic Pharma,Pharma,Drugs and Medication
2        DPG                                   rubber                              Tires


Thank you! The dplyr solution will be super useful when there are lots of columns to join.

You mightt use aggregate(. ~ Name, toString, df1) in the first case, and aggregate(. ~ Name, c, df1) in the second. Note, that c version gives "list" columns, which can still be useful.
